# Raster product in PyQGIS does not produce correct results

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, raster-calculator, conditional

I'm trying to mask (set with no data values) pixels in a raster not fulfilling a condition based on another raster. It runs well but it produces huge numbers that are not the values in the raster that I want to mask.

If someone can try the code, can figure what is wrong with it?

```
import processing

lyr1 = QgsRasterLayer('C:/Users/LAPTOPJOSE/Desktop/prueba_normalizar_raster/negras.tif')      
conras = QgsRasterLayer('C:/Users/LAPTOPJOSE/Desktop/prueba_normalizar_raster/Insar_13_25_02_2021_coh.tif')
output = 'C:/Users/LAPTOPJOSE/Desktop/prueba_normalizar_raster/negras_null.tif'
entries = []

con=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
con.ref='con@1'
con.raster=conras
entries.append(con)

ras=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras.ref='ras@1'
ras.raster=lyr1
entries.append(ras)

#Set_null
calc=QgsRasterCalculator('"ras@1"/("con@1" > 0.65)',output,'GTiff',\
lyr1.extent(), lyr1.width(), lyr1.height(), entries)
calc.processCalculation()
```

It seems an error of the multiplying operator because it yields in very long figures even when multiplying two 32bits float rasters with the Raster Calculator tool. I attach a screenshot of the inputs ("Insar....coh" as con@1, "negras" as ras@1) and the resulting raster ("negras_null"):

[image: Example of results with huge numbers after multiplication]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was mixing different SRCs for the rasters involved in the operation.